# pass instance variable while using observer pattern in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm using observer pattern in rails. The "delivered_email" method in TestObserver will be called after notification email been sent out. How could I pass the instance variable in "notification" to the "delivered_email"? I could add it either in the header or subject. But it could pose security issue since user who received email could also see the variable. Is there any better way to solve it?

```
class GeneralMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def notification(data)
    @emails = data[:emails]
    subject = "#{@sender.to_s}"
    mail(:to => @emails, :subject => subject)
  end
end

class TestObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    begin
      # do something here
      puts @emails
    rescue => ex
      # do something here
    end
  end

ActionMailer::Base.register_observer(TestObserver)
```

Comment: What is the actual purpose, why does your observer need a bunch of emails in the callback for a single message?

Comment: the purpose is to use instance variable defined in the "notification" method. Here I only show a simple example to demonstrate my purpose.

Comment: I'm not stupid - you already stated that in your question. There does not seem to be a way to pass variables to A.M. observers besides stuffing it in the message which as you already have figured out is a bad idea. So maybe if you shared what you are actually trying to do with the data in the variable and not just your proposed solution "sending a variable".

Comment: Can you just take `message.to` value? It seems that it is equal to `@emails`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do want to send extended information to a mail observer – as I myself did – it can be done by monkey-patching your mailer a bit to use a custom class extending from `Mail::Message`.

Note that this requires setting an internal, undocumented attribute. In a future Rails version, it might not continue to work.

```
class ExtendedMessage < Mail::Message
  attr_accessor :extra_args
end

class ApplicationMailer
  before_action :patch_message

  def patch_message
    # Patch the internal attribute @_message to use our overridden class
    # that you can store extra attributes inside.
    # NOTE: If a future Rails version decides to change the internals, this could break.
    @_message = ExtendedMessage.new
  end
end

class MailObserver
  def self.delivered_email(mail)
    do_something_with mail.extra_args
  end
end
```